# OSMnx custom filtering

Tags: osmnx

I'm trying to filter an OSMnx query with a custom filter which excludes all highway=service except segments where service=bus.

I copied the network type 'walk' from the overpass and tried to implement a "highway!~service OR service~bus", in the following code in the final row:

```
walk = (f'["highway"]["area"!~"yes"]{settings.default_access}'  
  f'["highway"!~"abandoned|bus_guideway|construction|motor|no|planned|tertiary_link|primary_link|motorway_link|trunk_link|platform|'

f'proposed|raceway|razed"]'

f'["foot"!~"no"]["service"!~"private|emergency_access|parking_aisle|parking|drive-through|driveway"]'

f'["highway"!~"service"]["service"~"bus"]'
    )
```

Which gives no data, as there are none which arent service and are bus.

Tried With different syntax which prompt errors:

```
f'["highway"!~"service"]**|**["service"~"bus"]'

f'["highway"!~"service"**|**"service"~"bus"]'
```

Tried with OR between the intial f' parts but with no results.

Whats the correct syntax then to implement a filter that includes only highway=service with service=bus, and exclude all other highway=service? the examples [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/08-custom-filters-infrastructure.ipynb) or [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/osmnx/_overpass.py) don't mention such a case, only hard exclusions.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720802/7321942